# Add single record to dataview in sencha touch 2.4.1

Tags: extjs, touch, store, record, dataview

I've created a DataView in my application:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Details', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    xtype: 'myapp-details',
    config: {
        itemTpl : '{title} + {description}'
    }
});
```

And in my controller I do something like this:

```
me.getMain().push({
    xtype: 'myapp-details',
    title: record.data.title,
    record: record
});
```

How do I add a single record to a dataview?